# Instagram API Enforce Signed Requests + Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match

Tags: c#, api, httprequest, instagram, instagram-api

I'am new to Instagram API, I have a client that needs to display the latest media on his website, but am doing the test under my personal Instagram account.

- Under Security Tab both [Disable implicit OAuth] & [Enforce signed requests] are checked.
- The Endpoint am trying to call is:  [users/{user-id}/media/recent]
- Signature Generation Method:

  ```
  string GenerateSignature(string endpoint, 
           Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string secret) {

      StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(endpoint);

      foreach (var param in parameters.OrderBy(p => p.Key))
      {
          message.AppendFormat("|{0}={1}", param.Key, param.Value);
      }

      return HMACSHA256_Hash(secret, message.ToString());
  }

  string HMACSHA256_Hash(string secret, string message)
  {
      // Create a HMAC-SHA256 digest of the message using the secret key
      HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
      byte[] digest = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.ToString()));

      // Return the digest as a hexstring to be used as a signature for the request
      return ByteArrayToString(digest);
  }

  string ByteArrayToString(byte[] array)
  {
      // Convert the bytes in the array to a lower-case hexstring
      return array.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, b) => sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"))).ToString();
  }
  ```
- Get Recent Media:

  ```
  protected void GetUserDetails()
  {
      string instagram_Username = "";
      string instagram_UserID = "";
      string instagram_AccessToken = "";
      string instagram_ClientID = "";
      string instagram_ClientSecret = "";

      int count = 1;

      string url = String.Format(@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{0}/media/recent?client_id={1}&count={2}", instagram_UserID, instagram_ClientID, count);
      string endPoint = String.Format("/users/{0}/media/recent", instagram_UserID);

      Dictionary<string, string> endPointParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      endPointParameters.Add("client_id", instagram_ClientID);
      endPointParameters.Add("count", count.ToString());

      string signature = GenerateSignature(endPoint, endPointParameters, instagram_AccessToken);
      url = url + "&sig=" + signature;
  }
  ```
- URL being called: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent?client_id={cliend_id}&count=1&sig=7c024d67c1000106686c412778dc3534614d43822f9e13554418c3d3d5386872
- Response: {"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match"}

IN ADDITION; can I please know if access token will expire Or I can use same one for all my calls, noting that the call will be done each time the home page of the website is rendered :-)

I appreciate the help ! many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've missed that the secret should be the client Secret.

```
string signature = GenerateSignature(endPoint, endPointParameters, instagram_ClientSecret);
```